# Convert every n # of rows to columns and stack them in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, matrix

I have a tab-delimited text file with a series of timestamped data. I've read it into R using `read.delim()` and it gives me all the data as characters in a single column. Example:

```
df <- data.frame(c("2017","A","B","C","2018","X","Y","Z","2018","X","B","C"))
colnames(df) <- "col1"
df
```

I want to convert every n # of rows (in this case 4) to columns and stack them **without using a for loop**. Desired result:

```
col1 <- c("2017","2018","2018")
col2 <- c("A","X","X")
col3 <- c("B","Y","B")
col4 <- c("C","Z","C")
df2 <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)
df2
```

I created a for loop, but it can't handle the millions of rows in my df. Should I convert to a matrix? Would converting to a list help? I tried `as.matrix(read.table())` and `unlist()` but without success.

Comment: If we combine `as.matix` and `unlist`, it works. As in `matrix(unlist(read.table()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tidyr` to reshape data into the form you want, you will first need to mutate the data as to identify which indexes should be first, and which go with a specific column.

Assuming you know there are 4 groups (`n = 4`) you could do something like the following with the help of the `dplyr` package.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
n <- 4
df <- data.frame(x = c("2017","A","B","C","2018","X","Y","Z","2018","X","B","C")) %>%
  mutate(cols = rep(1:n, n()/n),
         id = rep(1:(n()/n), each = n))
pivot_wider(df, id_cols = id, names_from = cols, values_from = x, names_prefix = "cols")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>      id cols1 cols2 cols3 cols4
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 2017  A     B     C    
#> 2     2 2018  X     Y     Z    
#> 3     3 2018  X     B     C
```

Or, in `base` you could use the `split` function on the vector, and then use `do.call` to make the data frame

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c("2017","A","B","C","2018","X","Y","Z","2018","X","B","C"))
split_df <- setNames(split(df$x, rep(1:4, 3)), paste0("cols", 1:4))
do.call("data.frame", split_df)
#>   cols1 cols2 cols3 cols4
#> 1  2017     A     B     C
#> 2  2018     X     Y     Z
#> 3  2018     X     B     C
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! The tidyr and dplyr approach worked great. Just a 5 second run time on my full dataset--so fast.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a matrix with `matrix(ncol=x, byrow=TRUE)`, then convert back to data.frame. Should be quite fast too.

```
df |>
        unlist() |>
        matrix(ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) |>
        as.data.frame() |>
        setNames(paste0('col', 1:4))

  col1 col2 col3 col4
1 2017    A    B    C
2 2018    X    Y    Z
3 2018    X    B    C
```